# Other side of the world seemingly reflected in Fresnel layer; only shows in render, not in viewport

Tags: rendering

I am very confused right now. I am making an Earth. The scene has two layers, atmosphere and ground/clouds. Rendering them individually gives me the results I want for each layer. Specifically, here is the atmosphere layer:
[image]

But when I render both layers together I get something hideous like this:
[image]

Do you see that hideous fog on the image? That is actually a mirror image of Africa and Europe, somehow being reflected onto the fresnel. I have no idea what is causing this, and would greatly appreciate any insight.

You can download the blend from here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47222

**UPDATE1** Turning diffuse bounces down to 0 worked. I am not happy with this solution.

**UPDATE2** Keeping diffuse on and turning glossy bounces does NOT work. Neither does turning off the "Glossy" option under `Ray Visibility` in the `Object` tab. Again, I am not happy with this solution.

Comment: When uploading a blend file please pack the textures and use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload the files. pasteall.org only stores the files temporarily, once the link is gone your question will not be as useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too. Here is how I fixed it. I went to User Preferences and I click on system and disabled Mipmaps

Hope this helps